# Need site to direct itself to /html.finds.html

Tags: html, path, relative-path

I want my site to redirect itself to the relative path: instead of   but it does not seem to be picking up the page that I want it to use. Am I placing the in the correct spot in order for it to work?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <title>Finds</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon-16x16png" type="image/png"/>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
       <link href='styles.css? version=1' rel='stylesheet'></link>
       <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="/css/finds.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>




    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
                <div class="left-col">

                    </div>
                <div class="right-col">
                  </div>
                <div class="header-slogan">
                    <h1>One Bug Design</h1>
               <div class="tag-line">
<h2>Designed to create<sup><small>&#153</small></sup></h2>
                </div>
            </header>
            <aside>
            <aside>
                <nav id='cssmenu'>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                      <li class='active'><a href="/html/finds.html">Finds</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </aside>
            <main
               <div id="content"
      </div>
       </nav>
       <main class="content">
           <div class="wrap">
           </div> <img src="/images/Pictures-Canon-icon.png" style="margin:0px 20px"> <div class="svg-wrapper">
  <svg height="60" width="320"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect class="shape" height="60" width="320"/>
  <div class="text">FINDS</div>
  </svg>
  </div>
  <br>
 <br>
 <br>
  <br>
 <strong><br><p>Warning!!! (The following pictures were taken with an actual camera.)</p><br></strong>
  </div>
    <div id="nav">
  <nav class="sitemenu">
   <div class="navwrapper">
   <div class="ease"></div>
      </div>

<div id="wowslider-container1">
<div class="ws_images"><ul>
        <li><a href="www.onebugdesign.com" target="_blank"><img src="data1/images/1452030768191_775358.jpg" alt="Sunbee" title="Sunbee" id="wows1_0"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="www.onebugdesign.com" target="_self"><img src="data1/images/1452030783386_195729.jpg" alt="Mushrooms" title="Mushrooms" id="wows1_1"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="www.onebugdesign.com" target="_self"><img src="data1/images/1452030877190_882834.jpg" alt="The Crossover" title="The Crossover" id="wows1_2"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="www.onebugdesign.com" target="_self"><img src="data1/images/1452030934369_512575.jpg" alt="B-ball splash" title="B-ball splash" id="wows1_3"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="www.onebugdesign.com" target="_self"><img src="data1/images/pumkinlovehires.jpg" alt="Pumpkin Love" title="Pumpkin Love" id="wows1_4"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="www.onebugdesign.com" target="_self"><img src="data1/images/1452030951286_336373.jpg" alt="Pop of Pink" title="Pop of Pink" id="wows1_5"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="www.onebugdesign.com" target="_self"><img src="data1/images/1452030966487_954820.jpg" alt="Spy in Winter" title="Spy in Winter" id="wows1_6"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="www.onebugdesign.com" target="_self"><img src="data1/images/1452031055435_871154.jpg" alt="Violin Boy" title="Violin Boy" id="wows1_7"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="www.onebugdesign.com" target="_self"><img src="data1/images/1452031366348_901054.jpg" alt="Storm'in" title="Storm'in" id="wows1_8"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="www.onebugdesign.com" target="_self"><img src="data1/images/1452031168621_846925.jpg" alt="Color Blended" title="Color Blended" id="wows1_9"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="www.onebugdesign.com" target="_blank"><img src="data1/images/1452031351430_823911.jpg" alt="Sky Bound" title="Sky Bound" id="wows1_10"/></a></li>
    </ul></div>
    <div class="ws_bullets"><div>
        <a href="#" title="Sunbee"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/1452030768191_775358.jpg" alt="Sunbee"/>1</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Mushrooms"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/1452030783386_195729.jpg" alt="Mushrooms"/>2</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="The Crossover"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/1452030877190_882834.jpg" alt="The Crossover"/>3</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="B-ball splash"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/1452030934369_512575.jpg" alt="B-ball splash"/>4</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Pumpkin Love"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/pumkinlovehires.jpg" alt="Pumpkin Love"/>5</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Pop of Pink"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/1452030951286_336373.jpg" alt="Pop of Pink"/>6</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Spy in Winter"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/1452030966487_954820.jpg" alt="Spy in Winter"/>7</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Violin Boy"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/1452031055435_871154.jpg" alt="Violin Boy"/>8</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Storm'in"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/1452031366348_901054.jpg" alt="Storm'in"/>9</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Color Blended"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/1452031168621_846925.jpg" alt="Color Blended"/>10</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Sky Bound"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/1452031351430_823911.jpg" alt="Sky Bound"/>11</span></a>
    </div></div>
<div class="ws_shadow"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: going to try htaccess re-direct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the links pointing to your domain, use `href="mylink.html"`. For the links pointing to external domain, don't forget to use http protocol name before www like this: `href="http://www.onebugdesign.com"`.